# SSH error : PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 shell request failed on channel 0

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh

I am trying to ssh into a TP-Link WR841N router and I am unable to do so, following is the output that I get if I try that in verbose mode, fellow experienced folks please take a look into it and tell me if you can see what is the issue.
( No configuration is made in the router to disallow ssh or anything)
Please feel free to ask for any further details if required.

[snapshot of the error generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELbKw.png)

Thanks